# How to make infinite scrolling <div>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried to make this div with columns move down infinitely - [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjswj.png), like on this google developer page - [Google developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/infinite-scroller) || [Infinite scroller image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MssUX.png), but as you see, unsuccessfully. So I have `<div>` called "imgs", with some quantity of images, and when "imgs" in some position, images from the bottom of the div, are moved to the top, but user shouldn't see them move.
Here are some of my works:

```js
let imgsContainer = document.getElementById("imgs");
let imgAppear = document.getElementById("imgAppear");

function imgsContainerMove() {
         let top = 0;
         setInterval(imgsContainerMoving, 25);

         function imgsContainerMoving() { // Animation
                   top++;
                   imgsContainer.style.top = top + '%';
                   if (top === 100) top = 0; //Top reset

                   if (imgsContainer.style.top == "1%") {
                    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.imgs > img")).slice(-6).forEach((image) => imgAppear.prepend(image)) //Adding images to the top
                }

            }
        }
        imgsContainerMove(); // execute function
```

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}
.gallery-block {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2B3C35;
}

.gallery-bg {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.gallery-bg .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: auto;
    background: rgb(43, 60, 53);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(43, 60, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(1, 2, 2, 0) 50%, rgba(43, 60, 53, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(43, 60, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(1, 2, 2, 0) 50%, rgba(43, 60, 53, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(43, 60, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(1, 2, 2, 0) 50%, rgba(43, 60, 53, 1) 100%);
}

.imgs {
    position: absolute;
    width: 75vw;
    columns: 200px;
    column-gap: 15px;
}

.imgs img {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-block">
  <h2>Gallery</h2>
  <img src="img/triangle.png" alt="" class="triang">
  <div class="gallery-bg">
      <div class="imgs" id="imgs">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/244/300/200.jpg?hmac=EveIsD4iO8woArdqcsJM76yYG6rwDR7OmPuPRwxh_1w">
        </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css file give **overflow:auto** instead of overflow:hidden